# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in php

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to connect database and fetch details, but it is showing an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

I am trying:

```
<?php
class Database
{

    private $host = "******";
    private $db_name = "******";
    private $username = "******";
    private $password = "******";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;    
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

The `prepare` code is defined in **class.user.php**:

```
<?php
require_once 'lang.php';
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
class USER
{   
    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }
//More codes...
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no call to prepare in your code

Comment: the current code doesn't have any `prepare` code.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have edited my question with `prepare` code.

Comment: $this->conn-> might be null, just use $conn->prepare($sql);

Comment: What's `$sql` return

Comment: show your code where you used prepare($sql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred due to connecting `MySQL` database which does not allow external access!

Sorry `commentors` for troubling you.